# ASP.NET login control mysteriously stops working

Tags: asp.net

I'm using the ASP.NET Login control and have been doing so for a couple of years on a particular site with success. Out of the blue, in the dev environment, this control has stopped working and is now bouncing me back to the login page.

Using source control I've reverted recent changes that might have been the cause but no luck. I've stepped through the code and have checked that the e.Authenticated property is correctly being set to true and that the ReturnUrl is correctly specified on the params.

Any ideas about where to look next to try and figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

After logging in are you being redirected to a page that you don't have authorisation for?

Comment: Do you have cookies disabled in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

I would check the following...

- Cookies still set in the browser
- SSL settings in conjunction with http
  not forwarding onto https
- Cert issues (old, new, expired)
- Changes in the domain that the user
  is authenticating to
- Essentially, check everything except
  your code, it works like you said. 
  ;-)